# I need some help for the sensor SDP600 using arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors

How to get the sensor values from the sdp600 using an arduino yun?

I have acquired the device address using the i2c scanner. This means that the connection is properly set. I just need the code to get the sensor values.

Comment: Do you have any specific trouble or errors during writing code and compiling it?

Comment: We are not writing your code. Look in the datesheet https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Differential_Pressure_Sensors/Sensirion_Differential_Pressure_Sensors_SDP6x0series_Datasheet_V.1.9.pdf to get the I2C specifications and commands (Page 4 and 5)